# "Cannot find getter/setter for field" caused by language specific characters

Tags: android, android-studio

I had been getting "cannot find getter/setter" errors from libraries like Room and Firebase even though the camel-case syntax seemed right. This error applied only to fields which had names starting with "i".

Uppercase of "i" is "İ" in my language and it turns out the compiler is looking for "İ" instead of "I". So for example if the field name is "id", Room looks for a method with name of "getİd".

How do I disable this feature?

Edit: yes i can just replace all 'I's with 'İ' or rename fields to something else and that would solve it. But thats just weird and i would like to stay in standart way.

UPDATE : With Android Studio 3.3 I also have to change I to İ in gradle files, else they give an error. example: testImplementation to testİmplementation

Comment: Interesting case. What language? Turkish?

Comment: `the compiler is looking for "İ" instead of "I"` any proofs of this statement? can you share more details - error message, stack trace, Room and Firebase versions?

Comment: Yes turkish language

Comment: i dont have a hard proof for that, figured it out by manually changing I to İ and error was gone

Answer (score 0):

You could change the template.
Here is class named Test:

```
public class Test {
    int id;


}
```

press `Alt + Insert` and click Getter, it will pop up a dialog
[image]

click `...` button, you will see the template:
[image]

now replace with

```
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
```

with

```
#set($name = $helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))
```

now the getter name should be `getid`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in IntelliJ IDEA code generator or libraries that you use. While the correct solution is to contact IntelliJ IDEA support and submit bug report, we may have to wait a long time for the fix. Meantime, you can use the below workaround.

Do as [navylover said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53463012/1429387): open [Getter and Setter template dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-dialog.html), but do not modify the 'IntelliJ Default' template. Duplicate the template and replace

```
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
```

with

```
#set($name = $StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))
#if($name.charAt(0) == 'i')
    #set($name = 'İ' + $name.substring(1))
#else
    #set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($name))
#end
```

It's a simple workaround for leading 'i' capitalization. Apply the same fix for Setter template.

A full template should look like:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA modified Getter template for Turkish i character]